# Entity Framework 6 won't update record unless I breakpoint my code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Edit: There's no issue here and I don't know whether or not to delete the question**... As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120538/entity-framework-6-wont-update-record-unless-i-breakpoint-my-code?noredirect=1#comment52139056_32120538), the whole thing was my bad. In the meantime, below are some nice drawings of my database and EntityFramework configuration. And some database tables.

I have the following two tables in my database (among others, these are the relevant ones):

[image: Signals]

It's possible that the `GroupId` field in `SignalMetaData` is null until the `GroupMetaData` entry is received by my application. With that said, here is my code to update a `SignalMetaData` record to provide its `GroupId` field once it's been received. `this._entities` is my EF object.

```
/// <summary>
/// Maps a signal to its group in the database
/// </summary>
/// <param name="signalId">The SignalId</param>
/// <param name="groupId">The identifier of the group that SignalId belongs to.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool InsertSignalGroupMapping(Guid signalId, Guid groupId)
{
    try
    {
        var sig = this._entities.SignalMetaDatas
                                .SingleOrDefault(signal => signal.SignalId == signalId);
        if (sig != null) 
        {
            sig.GroupId = groupId;
            this._entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this._logger.Log(LogSeverity.Error, ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The `this._entities.SaveChanges();` call doesn't seem to do anything when I test my application. I query the database and the record is not updated. It's like the method was never called. If I breakpoint the line with `sig.GroupId = groupId;` and then step through the `SaveChanges()` call, it has no problem. The record is updated and everything works fine.

I've tried adding this line between the assignment of `GroupId` and the `SaveChanges()` call:

`this._entities.Entry(sig).State = EntityState.Modified;`

with the same outcome. I've also tried using this call to update the record:

`this._entities.SignalMetaDatas.AddOrUpdate(sig);`

to no avail. I've added Console writes in the method and gone through without breakpoints and the Console writes appear. The method is being called but it's just doing nothing unless I breakpoint and step through manually.

One other thing I should mention: both `signalId` and `groupId` passed to the `InsertSignalGroupMapping` method are not null or empty guids, verified with `Console.Writeline`.

I've also tried assigning the `GroupMetaData` navigation property on the `sig` object to a fully qualified group object containing the ID passed to `InsertSignalGroupMapping` with the same outcome.

Per request, here is the model classes for the two objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class GroupMetaData
{
    public GroupMetaData()
    {
        this.GroupHierarchiesParentId = new HashSet<GroupHierarchy>();
        this.GroupHierarchiesGroupId = new HashSet<GroupHierarchy>();
        this.SignalMetaDatas = new HashSet<SignalMetaData>();
    }

    public System.Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupHierarchy> GroupHierarchiesParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupHierarchy> GroupHierarchiesGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SignalMetaData> SignalMetaDatas { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class SignalMetaData
{
    public SignalMetaData()
    {
        this.SignalHierarchiesSignalId = new HashSet<SignalHierarchy>();
        this.SignalHierarchiesParentId = new HashSet<SignalHierarchy>();
        this.SignalValues = new HashSet<SignalValue>();
    }

    public System.Guid SignalId { get; set; }
    public string SignalName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual GroupMetaData GroupMetaData { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SignalHierarchy> SignalHierarchiesSignalId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SignalHierarchy> SignalHierarchiesParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SignalValue> SignalValues { get; set; }
}
```

and the EF Config:

[image: EF Config]

Comment: Do you have `sig.Group` navigation property in your model as well?

Comment: Yes I have that property. I forgot to mention but I hacked together a solution where I passed a fully qualified `GroupMetaData` object to the `sig` object as well. Nothing.

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.6? Because unless you've applied a patch, there's a JIT bug that may explain this situation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this bug?

Comment: Can you create a brand new solution and add the bare minimum code to reproduce the bug?

Comment: This makes me sad, but in the interest of science. Yes.

Comment: I have encountered a similar issue. It works fine when I use a breakpoint. But it turned out to be related to an hardware initialization issue. The breakpoint gave a little more time to avoid transient issues. Not sure if you have any threading or a similar part that might affect this code. One way to find out is to place thread.sleep at the breakpoint and run it.

Comment: @XtremeBytes I thought of this as well. Although come to think of it, I used a `Thread.Sleep(0)` with a stopwatch to wait a specified amount of time instead of blocking the thread. I will try with a blocking sleep.

Comment: The mapping for foreign key `GroupId` and navigation property `GroupMetaData ` is correct? `GroupMetaData ` is lazyloaded? can you please add the model classes and EF config, so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Have you turned off AutoDetectChangesEnabled? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj556205.aspx

Comment: I created a new solution with basically the same table mapping and it worked properly. 

`GroupMetaData` is lazyloaded. I turned it off completely for the whole context and it didn't do anything. 

I turned off `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` as per that MSDN article and got the same result.

Comment: I will add the model classes to my question

Comment: @Brandon Because the new solution works, the question is now, what's different? Console app vs Web app? Do you override SaveChanges? Any other components that latch on to EF?

Comment: @cadrell0 Windows Service (actual) vs Console App (test). In both I use EF straight out of the box, the only thing differing is the DB Schema and connection strings. I have exclusive access to both databases and only one class using EF in both. The thing that is really exploding my brain is that breakpointing makes it work. I've gone over my debugging configuration with a fine-tooth comb and can't see anything that would cause something to evaluate that would force it to work.

Comment: Maybe it's silly question, did you tried to set both the navigation and foreign key together?

Comment: Honestly I'll try anything at this point because I have absolutely no idea what to do now.

Comment: What if you set the break point after the save? I want to know if there is watch or something that requests something from context.

Comment: Alright... I was really hoping that this wasn't the case and that I was just seeing things but: This is a case of developer incompetence and not an issue with EntityFramework. Note to future self: When you update a value in the database in one method, **don't overwrite the update with an insert in the next method call**. I need a drink.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have a watch or something else in your debugging environment that is manipulating the context in a way that causes it to "work".

The standard method is to set the navigation property instead of the ID. Something like:

```
var sig = this._entities.SignalMetaDatas
                        .SingleOrDefault(signal => signal.SignalId == signalId);
var group = this._entities.Groups
                          .SingleOrDefault(g => g.groupId == groupId);

if (sig != null) 
{

    sig.Group = group;
    this._entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I read that this was the "standard" way but that requires me to hit the database an extra time just to get the group object when I already have the identifier. Not to mention that that `InsertSignalGroupMapping` is part of an interface that I've purposely gone out of my way to decouple from my database provider. Passing the group object that way requires me to couple my implementation to EF

Comment: And, my apologies, I commented above saying that I;d already tried to assign the group navigation property with the same outcome. I will add to my question to prevent confusion.

Comment: "Passing the group object that way requires me to couple my implementation to EF" - I didn't suggest you pass the `group` object.  I suggested you load the right `group` to the context, which prevents EF from trying to create a new `Group`.  I still think it's possible that you have something in your debugging environment (like a watch) that is manipulating your context to get it to work.

Comment: The other part to the comment: "but that requires me to hit the database an extra time just to get the group object when I already have the identifier."... I tried to load the group object from the database as you have  (successfully), and got the same result. I have no watches explicitly defined in my environment. The only thing that might do the same is my Locals browser. I will see what it is evaluating